# Web/PC interface for iPhone text Messaging

Tags: iphone, applications, messages, sms, pc

There is a great web app at https://messages.android.com that syncs with an Android phone's SMS/messaging to allow texting from the computer.

(This is great for those of us who type faster than we text on a little phone; and for those who are sitting at a desktop all day and don't want to open their phone to address every incoming text message.)

Is there an analog for iPhone Messages?  I.e., a web or PC app that can send and receive native text messages for an iPhone?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202549 No it seems as it is only for Apple to Apple communications.

Comment: @ankii – even worse: that only works if the computer in question is a Mac!

Comment: well apps like telegram are always there...

Comment: @ankii: As far as I can see Telegram, like WhatsApp, etc., does not interact with the native SMS/text apps of a smartphone.  They require all parties to use the separate apps.  When I'm on an Android I can receive and send texts through the phone *or* through messages.google.com and the counterparty can't tell the difference.  I'm looking for the same functionality on iPhone.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution on a Mac or a PC running Windows/*nix?

Comment: @NimeshNeema: Solution for Windows please.

Comment: I'm afraid nothing like this exists. If you are using a Mac, you can set up [text message forwarding](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208386).

Answer (score 2):

No web or PC interface are viable.

Just messages on macOS allows a non iOS interface, however all recent iOS devices have full keyboard support. Wired and wireless keyboards work great even on an iPhone and command tab app switching lets you rock keyboard shortcuts and navigate almost everything out of the box without a touch interface.

- https://www.macstories.net/?s=Keyboard
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202041
- Lightning to USB Camera Adapter - https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MD821AM/A

TLDR - hook you PC keyboard to your iPhone for fast messages texting and writing.